# Is this possible: `Waterfalling` Action Compositions in Play Framework (Scala)

Tags: playframework

Based on the documentation we can use `andThen` for 'chaining' the action compositions; but based on my understanding these cross-cutting action compositions are not related. But what about an action composition that needs the result of another action composition for further analysis?

You might say well merge them in one action, but then it will break the single-responsibility and open-close principles.

So the question here is: how can we get the right result of an action composition and feed it into another one? Can we achieve the following pseudo code in any shape or form:

`def example = ac2(ac1(param1)) {....} //Two types of analysis on request`

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.

If you create an action refiner `ActionRefiner[Request, MyCustomRequest]` that transforms a `Request` into a custom request type, like `MyCustomRequest` you can use any of the other action builders to either transform, refine or filter `MyCustomRequest`

If a programmer attempts to chain an action function for a request that is different from `MyCustomRequest` then the compiler will complain about "expecting `MyCustomRequest` actual `Request`"

The examples [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaActionsComposition) are not great, but specifically check out the `ItemAction` which first requires the request be transformed by the `UserAction` -- i think that might be what you are after?